# How to load a page at "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp" using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I try to load the html page "webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp" and get the page "webreg.802.org.tw/tre/start.asp" using Jsoup.

```
String param = "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp";
Document docs1 = Jsoup.parse(new URL(param).openStream(), "Big5", param);
System.out.println(docs1.toString());
```

i got doc of page  "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/start.asp". could it be solved?

however, i got the web site redirected to  "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/start.asp" and then click the image for a href code to href="stepB1.asp". the web browser can load that page webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp, also i could read the html code of it.
how could i load the page at webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp?

```
       <a href="stepB1.asp"><img src="img/1_b2.jpg" border="0" alt="-------"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect happens if the http request does not carry certain headers. In order to load that page, you first need to go to the `start.asp` page, collect the cookie(s) and then load the `stepB1.asp` with a request that carries the cookie in its request header. Secondly, the page requires a correctly set `Referer` header.

Try this:

```
String startUrl = "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/start.asp";
Map<String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect(startUrl).execute().cookies();
String stepB1Url = "http://webreg.802.org.tw/tre/stepB1.asp";
Document b1Doc = Jsoup.connect(stepB1Url)
                   .cookies(cookies)
                   .header("Referer",startUrl)
                   .get();
//do whatever you need doing. This is just a test if the form is there
Element formEl = b1Doc.select("form[action=stepB1.asp]").first();
System.out.println(formEl);
```